# Can I get 5120x2160 at 60Hz with Dell U4021QW + OptiPlex 7080 + Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, display, dell, 4k-monitor

I would like to run my ultrawide monitor at 5120x2160 and 60Hz. Right now, I only get 30Hz.

My setup:

- I am running Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
- The desktop is a [Dell OptiPlex 7080](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/optiplex-7080-desktop/7080_sff_ss/ports-and-connectors?guid=guid-20ce5ca0-20ff-40b2-9d6a-5dd9519ec809), with DisplayPort 1.4
- The monitor is a Dell U4021QW (connected with the DisplayPort)

`xrandr` gives me only the 30 Hz option for 5120x2160:

[image]

I tried [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

```
cvt 5120 2160
xrandr --newmode "5120x2160_60.00" 949.00 5120 5536 6096 7072 2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 5120x2160_60.00
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 5120x2160_60.00
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

Anyone can help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: your GPU (Intel UHD 630) is not capable of that resolution. According to Intel's website, it can do max 4k @ 60Hz

Comment: @Esther I guess there is nothing I can do there?

Comment: put a (cheap) GPU capable of that resolution into your computer? otherwise doesn't look like it.

Comment: If your system has a PCIe x16 slot, you could install a sufficiently powerful graphics card. Make sure it will actually fit in your system before purchasing it though - I made the mistake of not properly verifying the size of my GPU, and I had to literally use a pair of wire cutters on my desktop to cut off and bend enough pieces to force it to fit. (And the cover no longer goes on. :P)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/comments/l31wfy/is_it_possible_to_run_a_5k2k_ultrawide_with_intel/

Comment: Wondering if this may help https://dancharblog.wordpress.com/2020/08/18/5120x1440-49-ultrawide-on-intel-gpus/ It requires Windows, though...